# Get-Member doesn't show Count member on a (Start-Job) object?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

As far as I know `Get-Member` can display all the members of an object, but I'm seeing a `Count` member that I can't explain:

```
PS> $job = start-job {dir c:\ }
PS> $job | get-member -Force -View All -MemberType All | select-string Count
# outputs nothing
PS> $job.Count
1
```

Where is the Count member coming from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a synthetic property that was added in V3:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/06/14/new-v3-language-features.aspx

> You can now use Count or Length on any object, even if it didn’t have
>   the property.  If the object didn’t have a Count or Length property,
>   it will will return 1 (or 0 for $null).  Objects that have Count or
>   Length properties will continue to work as they always have.
>
> ```
> PS> $a = 42 
> PS> $a.Count 
> 1
> ```